# Stacked RBM vs. Bernoulli RBM

Tags: neural-networks, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I'm requested to implement mnist project using stacked RBM. I didn't find any implementation of RBM in keras or tensorflow. However, there is a [Bernoulli RBM in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.html).

Could you please guide me if they are the same? Can I make a stacked RBM using this package?

And in general, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same at all.

A stacked RBM is probably another name for a DBN (Deep Belief Network). It is derived from an RBM, but it's not an RBM.

A bernoulli RBM is an RBM where the nodes in the graph are bernoulli random variables.